# outlet connection error insert new outler connection

Tags: ios, swift

I want to set outlet connection Among edittext and class(SignUpViewController).
As shown in the picture , I set class for my view but when set outlet connection error

error text:
Could not insert new outlet connection: Could not find any information for the SignUpViewController

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the view controller file itself please and have the file inspector selected on the right when you do?

Comment: Based on this info alone. I’m suspicious that either the class is named incorrectly in the code, or that the file is not part of the target.

Answer (score 1):

You may perform the following two steps only to get rid of this error.

```
1.  Clean Project using Product -> Clean Build Folder.
2.  Run the Project.
```

Now you can try to add/Connect the actions or outlets.

Worked for me many times and might work for you as well

Answer (score 1):

You should select `Module` below `Class`

[image]

Select File Inspector and Check Target membership for the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: i cant select Module below Class. textbox and dropdown box is empty

Comment: @alinn Then in file inspector select your membership. I updated my answer.